# ld: framework not found error in xcode 8

Tags: ios, cocoapods, swift3, ios10, xcode8

I am using xcode 8 for development and cocoapods 1.0.1 for frameworks. After installing frameworks, i couldn't able to build my project. I am getting "ld: framework not found" error. I am using following lines in pod file:

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'Sample' do

use_frameworks!

pod 'MBProgressHUD', '~> 0.9'
pod 'TPKeyboardAvoiding', '~> 1.2'
pod 'SDWebImage', '~> 3.7'
pod 'UIActivityIndicator-for-SDWebImage'
pod 'UITextView+Placeholder', '~> 1.2'
pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.0'

end

post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
            config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '3.0'
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: "CocoaPods 1.1.0+ is required to build Alamofire 4.0.0+." per the documentation here: https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#migration-guides

Answer (score 2):

After installing the frameworks, did you closed your project and opened the newly created workspace?

Once you start using CocoaPods to install framework, you must use the workspace as it includes your Sample project and the Pod project containing the frameworks.

In you project directory, make sure to open the .xcworkspace instead of .xcodeproj.

Edit:
If that is not the issue, go to your Sample target/General/Linked Framework and Librairies

You should only have one that should be name something like: Pods_Sample.framework

If you are only using cocoa pods to install frameworks it should be the only one there as it includes all the pods.

Answer (score 1):

select your target -> General ->Embedded Binary , click ＋ ，and add Alamofire.framework

Answer (score 0):

try adding `project 'APP_NAME.xcodeproj'` to your podfile after `use_frameworks!` and do `pod install` again

if you receive warnings like below, after `pod install`

```
[!] The `APP_NAME [Debug]` target overrides the `FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS` build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-BasePods-APP_NAME/Pods-BasePods-APP_NAME.debug.xcconfig'. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation
```

Go to **Build Settings** of your target and add `$(inherited)` to **Framework Search Paths**

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, and it happened a while after renaming my project.
It was using my Pod_Old_Project_Name as a framework.

I fixed this by going to Build Phases -> Link Binary With Libraries, and removed that framework.

Answer (score 0):

There are two reasons this error occurs

1. I have faced the same issue, This comes only due to **change in the 
   pod file or maybe the pod file may not exist**, double check the pod
   file and run the cmd **pod install**
2. After successfully installing the **pod** file still if you getting this
   error please **restart the Xcode, error goes away**