# Framework not found error Xcode 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode8

I am facing an xcode error after `pod install`,
that says 
[image]
. while building my app on xcode 8 .My pod is :

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, ‘9.3’

use_frameworks!

target ‘CabGuardPro’ do
    pod 'GoogleMaps','~> 1.10.5'
    pod 'Canvas', '~> 0.1.2'
end
```

I already have tried all of following links:

1.[ld: framework not found Parse Xcode 7 beta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31295369/ld-framework-not-found-parse-xcode-7-beta/31298214)
2.[Pod Error in Xcode "Id: framework not found Pods"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31139534/pod-error-in-xcode-id-framework-not-found-pods?answertab=active#tab-top)
3.[ld: framework not found error in xcode 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39661296/ld-framework-not-found-error-in-xcode-8)

Can anyone please tell me what am I doing wrong,Thanks in advance

Comment: Try updating CocoaPods using following command in terminal 'sudo gem install cocoapods' . Then do pod install again.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was XCode 8.1 - CocoaPods 1.1.1 problem after updating.

Assuming you've already tried following commands in terminal:

- `sudo gem install cocoapods`
- `pod install`

and it didn't helped

---

This has fixed it for me:

1. Open up the workspace.
2. Click on the blue project icon (that expands into your file tree) on the left hand side of the screen
3. Just to the right, select "Targets" (as opposed to "Project"--Project is blue, Target is like a pencil and a ruler and a paintbrush making a triangle)
4. Click on the General tab
5. Go to the "Linked Frameworks and Libraries" section (all the way at the bottom)
6. There are two Pods framework
7. Delete one of them

(can't tell you which one to delete - looks like you need pick one yourself and if it didn't help - then just try to delete another one).
In my case there were two, like:

- Pods.framework
- Pods_-abstract_target-_-target_name-.framework

And I've deleted the first one.

Comment: i already have tried that, that ends with 6 new errors . so eventually i had to remove "Canvas" framework to run my app. Anyway Thanks for the reply